# Retrieving data from database using laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I would like someone to help me step by step laravel process in retrieving data from a database. This is what I have done. The problem is no data is being displayed. I am not so good in this and need some help. Thanks

**ViewController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\AddressBook;
use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class ViewController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all of the application's users.
     *
     * 
     */
      Public function getContacts(){

        $contacts= AddressBookModel::all();

        $data = ['contacts' => $contacts];
        
        return view('view')->with($data);

        }
        
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('contacts',[
    'uses'=>'AddressBook\ViewController@getContacts'
]);
```

The Route is working well and its connecting and display the content in view.blade.php

**view.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 align="center">These are the Registered Contacts in the Database</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
Controller :

```
    public function getContacts()
    {
         // Try to name your model Contact instead of AddressBookModel
         $contacts= AddressBookModel::all();// = Contact::all();       
         return view('view')->withContacts($contacts);
    }
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 align="center">These are the Registered Contacts in the Database</h2>
 <table>
 <!-- I assume that name and phone are contact model attributes-->
 <th>Name</th> 
 <th>Phone</th>
 @foreach ($contacts $as $contact) 
    <tr>
        <td> {{$contact->name}} </td>
        <td> {{$contact->phone}} </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
 </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. It helped me achieve it well, though this worked

Answer (score 0):

I added this function in the view.blade.php

```
    @foreach($contacts as $display) {{$display}}
    @endforeach
```